# Generics with Generators and Sequences in Swift

Tags: ios, swift, generator, sequence

I have a fairly good understanding of OO programming and Swift, however, one area that really leaves me stumped is **Generators** and **Sequences** (I am fine with the concept of protocols by the way).

For example, I completed this exercise from the Swift Guide (Apple)

*“EXPERIMENT Modify the anyCommonElements function to make a function that returns an array of the elements that any two sequences have in common.”*

Turning this:

```
func​ ​anyCommonElements​ <​T​, ​U​ ​where​ ​T​: ​SequenceType​, ​U​: ​SequenceType​, ​T​.​Generator​.​Element​: ​Equatable​, ​T​.​Generator​.​Element​ == ​U​.​Generator​.​Element​> (​lhs​: ​T​, ​rhs​: ​U​) -> ​Bool​ {   
    for​ ​lhsItem​ ​in​ ​lhs​ {
        for​ ​rhsItem​ ​in​ ​rhs​ {
            if​ ​lhsItem​ == ​rhsItem​ {
                return​ ​true
            }
        }
    }
    return​ ​false
}
```

Into this:

```
func anyCommonElements <T, U where T: SequenceType, U: SequenceType, T.Generator.Element: Equatable, T.Generator.Element == U.Generator.Element> (lhs: T, rhs: U) -> [T.Generator.Element]? {
var commonElements:[T.Generator.Element]? = nil
    for lhsItem in lhs {
        for rhsItem in rhs {
            if lhsItem == rhsItem {
                if (commonElements == nil)
                {
                    commonElements = []  //init the array if not already
                }
                commonElements?.append(lhsItem) //add matching item to the array
            }
        }
    }
    return commonElements? //return nil or array of matched elements
}
```

I'm happy with the solution I've written and it works well, including the Optional return, however I am lost as to why the type of the commonElements return array **needs to be this**:

```
var commonElements:[T.Generator.Element]
```

**Rather than this:**

```
var commonElements:[T]
```

I've read a fair bit on the subject, including:

https://schani.wordpress.com/2014/06/06/generators-in-swift/

http://robots.thoughtbot.com/swift-sequences

http://natashatherobot.com/swift-conform-to-sequence-protocol/

But I am still completely lost - can someone please help explain this in simple terms or is it just a little abstract and not easy to describe?

Would really appreciate it,
Thanks, John

**Update for Swift 5:**
(using `Sequence` instead of `SequenceType`, `Iterator` instead of `Generator`, and new `Where` syntax.

```
func anyCommonElements <T, U> (lhs: T, rhs: U) -> [T.Iterator.Element] where T: Sequence, U: Sequence, T.Iterator.Element: Equatable, T.Iterator.Element == U.Iterator.Element {
    var commonElements:[T.Iterator.Element] = []
    for lhsItem in lhs {
        for rhsItem in rhs {
            if lhsItem == rhsItem {
                commonElements.append(lhsItem) //add matching item to the array
            }
        }
    }
    return commonElements //return nil or array of matched elements
}
```

In fact, you can just do `T.Element` now, and forget about the Iterator.

Comment: Is the problem that you don't understand where the names `Generator` and `Sequence` come from? Or is it that you don't understand what they _mean_?

Comment: **As an aside that doesn't answer the question, but addresses the experiment**: it would be more interesting to return a generator so that lazy-loading could still be effective. The problem that you've been asked to solve forces you to load all of the items to compare then and then return a populated array.

Comment: @IanMacDonald thanks Ian, interesting - I don't suppose you have an example where a generator is returned?

Answer (score 12, accepted):

T is a sequence type. For simplicity, let's take a special and familiar case and say T is an array.

Then the type of thing contained in the array is `T.Generator.Element`. This is because of the way the Array struct is defined. Keep in mind that Array is a *generic*. It is a SequenceType, which is a (generic) protocol with an empty type alias Generator, which is constrained to be a GeneratorType, which in turn is a (generic) protocol that has an empty type alias Element. When the generic is specialized, those empty type aliases are "filled in" with an actual type. All sequences are like that. So if T is an Array, then `T.Generator.Element` means "the *actual* type of *this* array's *actual* elements".

So `[T.Generator.Element]` means "an array of the same kind of element as the original array's elements.

Your proposed expression, `[T]`, would mean an array of *arrays*, which is not what we want.

Okay, now generalize T back to any sequence (array, string of character, etc.) and that explanation keeps on working.

Comment: It might help you to read my new Swift tutorial; here's the section on generics: http://www.apeth.com/swiftBook/ch04.html#_generics

Comment: YES, this is an awesome explanation. You are a legend. Ok one more thing - if the 'element' is effectively the type. What is the generator? ps. reading your tutorial now

Comment: Writing a generator, as @IanMacdonald has implied, is tricky. It needs to be able to get from one member to the next, preferably lazily. Watch the WWDC 2014 video on advanced Swift, which talks about this.

Comment: But _using_ a generator is easy: it is simply a thing guaranteed to have a `next` method. That is the basis of how `for...in` works in Swift. See my explanation here: http://www.apeth.com/swiftBook/ch05.html#_for_loops

Comment: wonderful book - you should charge for it! - one final question... when I look up the definition of SequenceType, I see that it has a typealias of Generator. So we are really saying "SequenceType".Element in effect. Thus am I right in saying Generator is a generic descriptor for the underlying container of any element?

Comment: No, we are really saying `SequenceType.Generator`. Then it turns out that Generator has a typealias of `Element`. So we can chain them.

Comment: The Swift people have set this up for more generality and power by having three protocols: sequence-or-collection, generator, and element. The intermediate generator is what allows you, among other things, to walk through a sequence-or-collection lazily, so that if it is big, you receive only one element at a time.

Comment: If Generator has a type alias of Element, are they not the same thing? I'm still struggling to understand what a Generator actually is! - sorry for repeating myself :) - EDIT Ahhh so the Generator is like a engine that allows interaction with the Sequence?!

Comment: Read the part of my book on generics. If a protocol has an empty type alias, it is a generic protocol. That type alias is a type that gets filled in when the generic is specialized. So Element is type that Generator _uses_ in its generic definition. And Generator is a type that Array (or whatever) _uses_ in its generic definition.

Comment: Thanks Matt! - you've been very helpful

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/68907/discussion-between-matt-and-woodstock).

Answer (score 5):

The author's answer is no longer valid for the latest version of Swift. Here is an update that is compatible with version 3.0.1, they have simplified how to make a generic array. *note: I originally used [Any] arrays, but updated the code based on the feedback below.*

```
func showCommonElements<T: Sequence, U: Sequence>(_ lhs: T, _ rhs: U) -> [T.Iterator.Element]
    where T.Iterator.Element: Equatable, T.Iterator.Element == U.Iterator.Element {
        var result:[T.Iterator.Element] = []
        for lhsItem in lhs {
            for rhsItem in rhs {
                if lhsItem == rhsItem {
                    result.append(lhsItem)
                }
            }
        }
        return result
}
```

You can test the code with the following commands:

```
showCommonElements([1, 2, 3, 4, 5], [4, 7, 3])
showCommonElements(["apple", "banana", "orange", "peach"], ["orange", "pear", "apple"])
```

Comment: I appreciate the response but I believe this is totally wrong. You should never use Any with generics. If you use Any you will be losing the type information that generics are designed to preserve. Where did you see this used by Apple? If you do it like you suggested the caller of the function receives an "Any" array. Generics allow a typed array to be returned.

Comment: Check this out, run this code and it will illustrate how the type information is lost. http://swiftlang.ng.bluemix.net/#/repl/5891c7af7a5c2d1425c7490c

Comment: I see, thank you for the constructive criticism. I'm brand new to Swift, so still learning proper practices. Perhaps the better way would be to replace all instances of `Any` in my code with `T.Iterator.Element` in order to maintain type information.
You use optional arrays in your sandbox example, is there any specific reason for doing so? As I said before, I'm new to the language, so I'm trying to learn good practices.

Comment: @Woodstock Also, with regards to stack exchange, should I edit this answer given your feedback? Delete this answer and post an updated answer? Or leave this one and post another?

Comment: ya please edit! I'll upvote then. Will get back on other points.

Comment: Okay, I've edited to remove any instances of `Any`. This also leads me to the question, what is a scenario where using `Any` is good?

Comment: I've upvoted :) - with regard to the optional arrays not really necessary, I made them optional as maybe we will find no matches and return nil... I asked further about when to use Any and the answer is when it's required, but it should be avoided... definitely in generics returning any defeats the purpose... We are all learning :)